# Framing the screen with character

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, masm

I want to fill the edge of the screen(80*25 resolution but the main problem is that i can not write to the last line) so its like 80*24 the resolution what i framed
and i i have some other issues.I will add these to the comments:

```
    Code    Segment
    assume CS:Code, DS:Data, SS:Stack

Start:
    mov    ax, Code
    mov    DS, AX


    ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    ;*              $
    ;*              $   
    ;*              $ 24 line
    ;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 25 line

;But what i get is

    ;****************
    ;*              $
    ;*              $   
    ;*              $ 23 line
    ;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 24 line

;If i try to use 24 iteration in the second cyclus(Line1) i get:

    ;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    ;*              $
    ;*              $   
    ;*              $
    ;*              < 24 line
    ;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  25 line



    mov ax,03h
    int 10h
    xor dx,dx

    xor dx,dx
    push dx

    mov cx,80
Line:   
    pop dx
    xor bx,bx
    mov ah,02h
    int 10h

    inc dl
    push dx

    mov dl,'>'
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h
loop Line


pop dx
dec dl
inc dh
push dx

    mov cx,23
Line1:   
    pop dx
    xor bx,bx
    mov ah,02h
    int 10h

    inc dh
    push dx

    mov dl,'$'
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h
loop Line1

 pop dx
 dec dh   
 push dx

     mov cx,80
Line3:   
    pop dx
    xor bx,bx
    mov ah,02h
    int 10h

    dec dl
    push dx

    mov dl,'<'
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h
loop Line3


;Hier the DX register is crashed somehow and i need to set it manually
;Do you know why?

 pop dx
 mov dh,22
 mov dl,0
 ;dec dh   
 ;dec dl

 push dx

     mov cx,22
Line4:   
    pop dx
    xor bx,bx
    mov ah,02h
    int 10h

    dec dh
    push dx

    mov dl,']'
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h
loop Line4



    xor ax,ax
    int 16h




ProgramEnd:
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h   
    pop bx

Code    Ends

Data    Segment

Data    Ends

Stack    Segment

Stack    Ends
    End    Start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a loop the `DX` on stack contents the **next** position.

1) Delete the `dec dh` before `Line3`. The "next" row is just the right row.

2) The "next" column before Line4 is "left from 00" = FF. Change the `dec dl` there to `inc dl` and you can remove your manual adjust.

3) `int 21h / ah = 02h` prints the character **and** moves the cursor. If the cursor leaves the window (right bottom) it will be scrolled. Use a function that doesn't move the cursor. So change

```
mov dl,'<'
mov ah,02h
int 21h
```

to

```
mov ah, 09h
mov bx, 7
mov al, '<'
int 10h
```

Comment: it works fine i use the ah,09h command so no more interference with cursor position.Sorry i can not vote it:(